# Magento: Activate customers in Admin Panel with having to send activation email

Tags: php, magento

I have a Magento store and I need to activate customers in Admin Panel without having to send an activation email so they can click on the link to be activate. At the moment I can validate the user in Admin Panel but I can not activate it.